# Timedatectl "Failed to parse bus message: Connection timed out" with systemd ExecPreStart while SELinux is enforcing

Tags: systemd, selinux, oracle-linux

Using Oracle Linux 8.6 we're having an issue with timedatectl but *only* when it's run by systemd(239-58.0.1.el8_6.3) during `ExecStartPre` in a .service definition file and SELinux is set to `Enforcing`.

**Important!**: The command `timedatectl show` **works** when run:

- By the user in the shell
- If we run it within a script under `ExecStart` instead of `ExecStartPre`
- If we run it directly in the `ExecStartPre` line as `ExecStartPre=timedatectl show`

### MinimalRepro:

/test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
timedatectl show
```

/usr/lib/systemd/system/test.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service

[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutStopSec=60s #This is necessary as this is a timeout issue
SyslogIdentifier=test
ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/bash /test.sh
ExecStart=echo "Done!"
```

With these files in place, run the command `systemctl start test`

#### Result:

The service fails to start. Journalctl shows `"Failed to parse bus message: Connection timed out"`

##### strace logs:

We managed to gather strace output during the failure. The relevant part (after dependency loads):

```
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "0\n", 2)                       = 2
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/system-fips", F_OK)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/system-fips", F_OK)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/gcrypt/fips_enabled", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "0\n", 1024)                    = 2
close(3)                                = 0
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_MAC_OVERRIDE) = 1
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x30 /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_CHECKPOINT_RESTORE) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND) = 1
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_PERFMON)     = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_AUDIT_READ)  = 1
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=217800224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 217800224, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3238c29000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/stat", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "14656 (timedatectl) R 14653 1463"..., 1024) = 313
close(3)                                = 0
access("/proc/vz", F_OK)                = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getpid()                                = 14656
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/systemd/container", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/1/environ", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0400, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "HOME=/\0TERM=linux\0BOOT_IMAGE=(hd"..., 1024) = 99
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/1/sched", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "systemd (1, #threads: 1)\n-------"..., 1024) = 1024
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/cmdline", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,msdos1)/vmlinuz-"..., 1024) = 183
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 3
fstatfs(3, {f_type=XFS_SB_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=18341120, f_bfree=16244361, f_bavail=16244361, f_files=36700160, f_ffree=36548894, f_fsid={val=[0xfc00, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/initrd-release", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/systemd/system/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 29) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}, [12]) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERSEC, "system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t"..., [64 => 36]) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERGROUPS, 0x55ed61e47c60, [256 => 0]) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, [0], [4]) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX}, [128 => 2]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\0AUTH EXTERNAL\r\nDATA\r\n", iov_len=22}, {iov_base="NEGOTIATE_UNIX_FD\r\n", iov_len=19}, {iov_base="BEGIN\r\n", iov_len=7}], msg_iovlen=3, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 48
gettid()                                = 14656
getrandom("\x26\x61\x8e\x0f\x4d\x7f\x4e\x6f\x8f\x4f\xfa\x3e\x40\xa5\xe0\x25", 16, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 16
gettid()                                = 14656
recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="DATA\r\nOK a4090baa394dcf0c365870c"..., iov_len=256}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 58
sendmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0m\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., iov_len=128}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 128
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
ppoll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, {tv_sec=24, tv_nsec=999768000}, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}], left {tv_sec=24, tv_nsec=999316712})
recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\2\1\1\f\0\0\0\1\0\0\0=\0\0\0\6\1s\0\7\0\0\0", iov_len=24}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base=":1.4092\0\5\1u\0\1\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0\7\1s\0\24\0\0\0"..., iov_len=68}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 68
sendmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\1\0\1\5\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\217\0\0\0\1\1o\0\32\0\0\0/org/fre"..., iov_len=160}, {iov_base="\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=5}], msg_iovlen=2, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 165
recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\4\1\1\f\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\215\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0", iov_len=24}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0"..., iov_len=148}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 148
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
ppoll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, {tv_sec=24, tv_nsec=999676000}, NULL, 8) = 0 (Timeout)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2997, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2997
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
writev(2, [{iov_base="Failed to parse bus message: Con"..., iov_len=49}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2) = 50
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

##### Log findings:

From the logs it seems clear to me that `timedatectl` did successfully reach out for information from the servers by the presence of the `recvmsg` commands throughout. However, the `ppol` on the socket with fd 3, doesn't appear to be closing correctly. Running `strace` with timestamps shows that `ppol` is the only command that is taking a significant amount of time and the `recvmsg` commands are done long before the timeout occurs.

#### Audit.log:

I found the following in the audit logs that coincide with the failures:

```
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1660774510.696:6426767): pid=1298671 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1660774510.697:6426768): pid=1298671 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 msg='cwd="/" cmd=74696D656461746563746C2073686F77 exe="/usr/bin/sudo" terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=CRED_REFR msg=audit(1660774510.697:6426769): pid=1298671 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=USER_START msg=audit(1660774510.706:6426770): pid=1298671 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1660774510.780:6426771): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-timedated comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1660774510.783:6426772): pid=966 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc:  denied  { send_msg } for msgtype=method_return dest=:1.3078967 spid=1298674 tpid=1298673 scontext=system_u:system_r:systemd_timedated_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 tclass=dbus permissive=0  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'UID="dbus" AUID="unset" SAUID="dbus"
```

#### Variations:

The following changes had *no effect* (error continued)

- Added a user/group definition to the test file and ran the ExecStartPre command as the user and as root
- Ran the script using /usr/bin/sh
- Ran the script using /usr/bin/zsh
- Ran the `timedatectl show` command under sudo

### Questions:

- What could potentially cause `ppol` to hang like this?
- How could we determine what it's actually waiting for when it seems the `recvmsg` commands have returned everything expected of them?
- Is there anything else we can do to SELinux to fix this besides setting it to `Permissive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question shortly after asking it (Though, I would still love to know why this occurs with `ExecStartPre` but not `ExecStart`, if anyone can clue me in on that).

The problem is that, by default, SELinux is blocking `initrc_t:dbus send_msg`. The easiest way to bypass this is setting SELinux to permissive, but that's obviously far from ideal. Instead, we need to create a policy with the following steps.

1. Install `policycoreutils-devel` with: `dnf install -y policycoreutils-devel`
2. After finding the audit msg number in the audit.log file (see audit.log snippet in question "1660774510"), feed the appropriate lines into the `audit2allow` utility to generate a policy file: `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep 1660774510 | audit2allow -M newPolicy`
3. Use `semodule` to apply the new policy: `semodule -i newPolicy.pp`

###### Note:

To incentivize other, possibly more detailed answers (hopefully explaining the ExecStartPre versus ExecStart thing), I'll hold off on accepting my own answer for now and will accept the best after some time has passed.